# How do I embed an SWF file in an HTML page without IE having a fit?

Tags: html, flash

I'm trying to get an HTML page to run a shockwave-flash video.  While I can do it no problem using:

```
<object width="350" height="263"> 
    <param name="movie" value="video/star.swf"> 
    <embed src="video/star.swf" width="350" height="263"> 
    </embed> 
</object>
```

IE will not run it without a two-stage verification that you want to do it.  The little yellow line at the top of the page that you click on to select "Allow blocked content", and then after clicking on that it wants another confirmation in a dialog box warning you that active content will cause the Apocolypse.

Is there a way to get it to not do this?  I could have sworn I have seen movies running on the web that don't do this kind of thing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These warnings will pop up only when you load the page from local drive - not when you load the page from a server. And it's not just for flash - these warnings pop up even if you have some javascript in your page.

Comment: Great!  I don't know why this never came up to me before.  Thanks so much!